# verifyerror with AspectJ's private method on android platform

Tags: java, android, aspectj, verifyerror

I met an odd problem related with AspectJ's advice. When I declare the function(below **private void gotNetType2()** ) as a private member function called by an around advice, when starting the apk, it failed with below error.

```
11-04 12:31:56.742: W/dalvikvm(2229): VFY: invoke type does not match method type of Lcom/bright/net/test/NetType2;.gotNetType2
11-04 12:31:56.742: W/dalvikvm(2229): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
11-04 12:31:56.743: W/dalvikvm(2229): VFY:  rejected Lcom/xxx/net/test/NetType2;.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_xxx_net_test_NetType2$com_xxx_net_test_NetType2$gotNetType2 (Lcom/xxx/net/test/NetType2;)V
11-04 12:31:56.743: W/dalvikvm(2229): Verifier rejected class Lcom/xxx/net/test/NetType2;

....
....
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229): java.lang.VerifyError: com/xxx/net/test/NetType2
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at com.xxx.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:1)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:157)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5326)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:848)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
11-04 12:31:56.863: E/AndroidRuntime(2229):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But after I changed the function to a public one( **public void gotNetType2()** ), the error disappeared.  I have tried to switch the sdk from 1.7 to 1.6 and also tried to build the target apk version as 4.1 as the same as my android phone. But the error still exists.

I got no idea why only private function failed. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

below is the aspectj code for your reference, which is very simple.

```
public aspect NetType2 {
    public final static String TAG = "NetTypeAspectJ";
    pointcut testMainActivity():execution(* com.xxx.main.MainActivity.onCreate(..));

    void around():testMainActivity()
    {
            proceed();
            gotNetType2();

    }
    private void gotNetType2() 
    {
            Log.e(TAG, "hahaha....");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. As a workaround, if the function is made static then it works ok. Can pass 'this' to the called function if need to operate on the class itself. I haven't got another solution to the problem, and its likely complex and at the compiler level.